# set "select" combobox to fixed size

Tags: android, jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

A part of my JQuery mobile powered webpage (used at an Android App) looks like this:

```
<table style="width:100%">
//here are some other rows with other input fields
<tr>
  <td>Combobox:</td>
  <td>
    <select id="sl_bnd">
      <option value="0">Very very very long text</option>
      <option value="1">Shorty</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The problem is that when the "Very very very long text" is selected, the combobox becomes wider showing half of the table out of the screen.

What I would like, is to set the combobox to the fixed initial size (which is dynamic since the screen may have different resolutions).

Does anyone know how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If you are using responsive mobile site,

Check here http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/vDeKq/2/

Since it is dynamic, set its width with dynamic.

```
$('#sl_bnd').css({
    'float':'left',
    'width': ($(window).width()-$('#c_label').width()-20)+'px' 
});
```

#### If you are using JQM, this problem is already solved.

DEMOhttp://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/vDeKq/4/

Comment: If you activate jQuery mobile, it does not work anymore. See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vDeKq/3/)

Comment: Oops..my bad, i thought it is responsive site.

Answer (score 2):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/HZAnz/

Just use simple CSS:

```
.ui-select, #sl_bnd, #sl_bnd option {
    width: 200px !important;
}
```

you can even use percentage:

```
.ui-select, #sl_bnd, #sl_bnd option {
    width: 80% !important;
}
```

or if you want to change specific select:

```
#custom-select .ui-select, , #sl_bnd, #sl_bnd option {
    width: 200px !important;    
}
```

Main thing is to use **`!important`** to override default values.

If you only want to change option width just use this css:

```
#sl_bnd, #sl_bnd option {
    width: 200px !important;    
}
```

Comment: with pixels it would be fixed, and with `%` it actually is a percentage of the item it would show. Meaning that shorty would be smaller than very very long text. Also, it breaks something regarding the opening of the combo box. Clicking on the right side of it won't open the selection anymore. See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HZAnz/3/)